# Why allocate a variable in rebol?

Tags: memory-management, rebol

I found a line like this in some Rebol code:

```
dups: make block! 10000
```

Why would you use pre-allocation in Rebol?

What's wrong with just writing:

```
dups: copy []
```

Answer (score 7):

First thing: you don't "allocate a variable" in Rebol, you "pre-allocate a series buffer" (which happens to be referenced by a word in your code example, but it could be just lying in a block).

Quick answer: each time you are INSERTing or APPENDing data to a series, if the series buffer is full, the series will be re-allocated by the memory manager to a bigger one. If you are extending a series multiple times (like appending data to the series in a loop), if you don't pre-allocate, you might end up consuming a lot of extra memory for all the re-allocations and probably at some point, also triggering garbage collector passes. This usually results in a big slowdown in the program execution and lot of extra memory consumed. Pre-allocating the series buffer to a big enough size to hold all the final data, will avoid all these memory and performances issues.

In the case of `dups: copy []`, you are allocating a minimal series buffer (with size of probably 8 or 16 slots), so if all your data doesn't fit in this buffer, your program will pay the (heavy) cost of re-allocation(s). Also `[]` is a pre-allocated literal series of minimal size that you are just using as a template to build a new series, so better avoid wasting memory for nothing and write instead: `dups: make block! 0` which will allocate a block! series of minimal size without wasting an extra block! series.

Comment: Do you use pre-allocating today? 
It makes sense with modern PC?

Comment: I just tested 

    >> a: make block! 10000
    >> b: copy []
    >> delta-time [loop 10000 [append a 1] ]
    == 0:00:00.004315
    >> delta-time [loop 10000 [append b 1] ]
    == 0:00:00.005795

Comment: Yes, I always use pre-allocation when I know that I will have a lot of insertions to do, even for small series (more of maintaining a good coding pratice than effective gain in such case). It matters when your series are big enough, regardless of the computing power you have, the difference can reach tremendous proportions with huge series (especially on memory usage).

Comment: There is one more thing with pre-allocation. If you use CALL/output to insert output into a string you MAY need to pre-allocate it otherwise it crashes sometimes if the output is too long. (on Windows)
s: make string! 1024
call/output "dir /s c:\" s

Answer (score 2):

pre-allocating a buffer is essential for the low level function read-io

if you need e.g. access to the exact error code when reading data you can use read-io instead of copy on opened ports.

read-io is comparable to READ in c-languages. 
You provide read-io with a pre-allocated fixed buffer and the buffer length.
If you try  read-io with a buffer length more than pre-allocated, you do that on your own risk

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think it is an answer to why would you use .. but to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

I just tested

```
>> a: make block! 10000
>> b: copy []
>> delta-time [loop 10000 [append a 1]]
== 0:00:00.004315
>> delta-time [loop 10000 [append b 1]]
== 0:00:00.005795
```

The difference is just less then a hundredth of a second.

Then I restarted rebol and tested:

```
>> a: make block! 10000
>> b: copy []
>> delta-time [loop 20000 [append a "test"]]
== 0:00:00.000238
>> delta-time [loop 20000 [append b "test"]]
== 0:00:00.000223
```

**No pre-allocation is faster then pre-allocation!**

Comment: A couple of notes:

* DELTA-TIME is not very reliable

* preallocating inadequate space does not make sense

Comment: Also, what is your "restarted" example supposed to test?

Comment: _The difference is just less then a hundredth of a second._

This is not how performances should be compared, the absolute time difference does not have much meaning, you need to look at the relative time difference, so: `0.005795 / 0.004315` gives you ~34% slower execution time when not preallocating.

Comment: Also you should test with various series size, you will see that the bigger the series, the bigger the impact on the execution time, so, the performance gap will grow with the series size. Another point you've missed is also comparing memory usage in both cases (you would need to run each test in a new Rebol session).

Comment: What is your second example supposed to test? It looks like corrupted code to me.

Comment: If I can't predict block size, and  pre-allocate 10'000 position, then I add 20'000 position... It seems that it's better to not pre-allocate.

Comment: You have only proved that not pre-allocating enough space is detrimental, that is what we are trying to explain.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Ladislav that probably **delta-time** is not reliable. However I don't think that a modern PC need to pre-allocating, there are tons of memory wasted for a simple browser plug-in. I believe that Rebol garbage collector is enough for ordinary use.
(Maybe in Android device speed and memory are still problems)

Comment: That has nothing to do with "modern PCs". (And absolutely nothing whatsoever with the size of browser plug-ins.)

As DocKimbel already explained, when a series buffer is full, it needs to be re-allocated, which could also involve copying all the existing series buffer's contents. If you already know how much storage you will need, not pre-allocating will *always* incur this re-allocation overhead, irrespective of how modern or not your PC is. Copying memory around is _not_ free, so it's only a question of _when_ (not if) this overhead will also come with a noticeable performance hit.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for being on StackOverflow--it's a good place for institutional knowledge, and questions like these are helpful.  However, be sure to make sure if you "answer" a question that it's an answer, not a comment!  I've upvoted your other answer to compensate for someone's downvote, but you should delete this one and make it a comment.  If you just want to chat, [join us in the Rebol and Red room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red)